# React Testing Library - TypeError: actImplementation is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm getting TypeError: actImplementation is not a function when trying a simple test for this component

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyledHeaderContainer, StyledTitle } from './styled';

export const Header = () => {
  return (
    <StyledHeaderContainer>
      <StyledTitle data-testid='title-test-id'>Subject Access Request</StyledTitle>
    </StyledHeaderContainer>
  );
};
```

This is my test

```
import * as React from 'react';
import 'jest-styled-components';

import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Header } from '../';
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

describe('Header', () => {
  it('is rendered correctly', () => {
    expect(<Header />).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});

describe('Title', () => {
    it('should have correct text', () => {
        render(<Header />);
        expect(screen.getByTestId('title-test-id')).toHaveTextContent('Subject Access Request');
    })
})
```

It is pointing to the `render(<Header /)` as the problem

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am facing similar issues, seems to be the problem with react-dom version 18

Comment: Can you post your package.json please

Comment: I had the same problem, and the problem was a wrong `moduleNameMapper` config in my jest.config. This issue has helped me https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1064#issuecomment-1122354171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after much trial and error it turned out to be a simple fix. I had applied this import in my test but not the component
`import * as React from 'react';`

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same error when using `react@17`, `react-dom@18` and `@testing-library-react@13`. Upgrading `react` to `18` solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately due to company policy I need to use the typescript version which isn't at 18 yet by the looks of things. Still this is helpful and I found another work around :)

Comment: Updating to React 18 also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing Header correctly change the import to:

```
import { Header } from '../Header';
```

(or whatever file is exporting the Header component)

Also your first test is not rendering a component so the test is failing.

Change it to:

```
it('is rendered correctly', () => {
 render(<Header />);
 expect(<Header />).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```